# Creating a gridview or listview from different sql tables in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, gridview

What i aim to achive with this is to have a grid or listview where the colums get data from different sql tabels.

Here are the different tabels

### TradeItemIdentification

> id 
>  GTIN

### TradeItemDescriptionInformation

> id 
>  brandName 
>  tradeItemFunctionalName

### ClassificationCategory

> id 
>  additionalClassificationCategoryCode

I don know if it is possible to show a grid with all of these attributes except the id's. What is the smartest way to do achive this, if possible?
They are all linked to this table. With these "many ot many" tabels.

### TradeItemBasic

> id

### TradeItemIdentificationOnTradeItem

> tradeItemId 
>  identificationId

### TradeItemDescriptionInformationsOnTradeItem

> tradeItemId 
>  descriptionId

And the same for the last table. So they have a connection.
Here is some joins of the tabels that i have made so far.

```
public List<string> GetAllProductsInfo()
    {
        var gtins = (from gtinss in _db.TradeItemIdentificationOnTradeItems
                     join gtin in _db.TradeItemIdentifications on gtinss.tradeItemIdentificationId equals gtin.id
                     select gtin.gtin);

        var brandNames = (from descriptions in _db.TradeItemDescriptionInformationsOnTradeItems
                         join description in _db.TradeItemDescriptionInformations on descriptions.tradeItemDescriptionInformationId equals description.id
                         select description.brandName);

        var article = (from articleNumbers in _db.ClassificationCategoryOnGDSNTradeItemClassifications
                       join articleNumber in _db.ClassificationCategories on articleNumbers.gDSNTradeItemClassificationId equals articleNumber.id
                       select articleNumber.additionalClassificationCategoryCode);

        var allInfo = gtins.Concat(brandNames).Concat(article).ToList();

        return allInfo;
    }
```

This is what ive got so far, i am no able to get all of the items that i wanted. But when i do it like this the results is not divided in to sections, but instead it is all just gets put out as one long list.

Comment: Is there any relationship between these tables?

Comment: if you use join query its possible, but need some relation between tables

Comment: no there are no relations between these tabel directly. They are all linked to a table called TradeItemBasic, with tables that has a id from TradeItem and Their own id's. Hope this is well enough explained

Comment: you have to take individual table data in data table then merge all data table then final data table bind into gridview.

Comment: @AnuragJain that sounds like a good plan. I just dont know how to do that many joins.

Comment: Ok, I can see the relationships now the OP has edited the post

Comment: post your code which you made it.

Comment: If all tables have a relation to TradeItemBasic then just use this table as master and left/inner join all these tables to that table in on clause. Select just the properties you want to display, load/fill them into the dataset/datatable and just bind the gridview.

Comment: @Tjasun could you write an example. I have never made inner joins. I have mostly worked with regualr joins.

Comment: @AnuragJain i have just posted som code above can you take a look?

Comment: did u want all variable values display into gridview ?

Comment: yes all of them. it is just a list of all the items in the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join the different tables and select the properties you want to display.
There are two different use cases. If you want to display all lines where some data is missing then use left joins. Else use inner joins (just replace the left join). That reduce your resultset.

Here is an example how to join your tables:

```
SELECT tib.id, tii.GTIN, tidi.brandName, tidi.tradeItemFunctionalName
FROM TradeItemBasic AS tib
LEFT JOIN TradeItemIdentificationOnTradeItem AS tii2ti ON tib.id = tii2ti.tradeItemId 
LEFT JOIN TradeItemIdentification AS tii ON tii.id = tii2ti.identificationId
LEFT JOIN TradeItemDescriptionInformationsOnTradeItem AS tidi2ti ON tib.id = tidi2ti.tradeItemId 
LEFT JOIN TradeItemDescriptionInformation AS tidi ON tidi.id = tidi2ti.descriptionId
```

For the ClassificationCategory you don't post a mapping table, so i remove the selected property.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I Made a new C# class. Called ProductInfo that looks like this

```
public class ProductInfo
{

    public ProductInfo()
    {

    }

    public List<string> Gtin { get; set; }
    public List<string> BrandName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ArticleNr { get; set; }

}
```

this class takes three types of lists.
And here is the method for getting the specific information from the different classes.

```
public ProductInfo GetAllProductsInfo()
    {
        var gtins = (from gtinss in _db.TradeItemIdentificationOnTradeItems
                     join gtin in _db.TradeItemIdentifications on gtinss.tradeItemIdentificationId equals gtin.id
                     select gtin.gtin).ToList();

        var brandNames = (from descriptions in _db.TradeItemDescriptionInformationsOnTradeItems
                         join description in _db.TradeItemDescriptionInformations on descriptions.tradeItemDescriptionInformationId equals description.id
                         select description.brandName).ToList();

        var article = (from articleNumbers in _db.ClassificationCategoryOnGDSNTradeItemClassifications
                       join articleNumber in _db.ClassificationCategories on articleNumbers.gDSNTradeItemClassificationId equals articleNumber.id
                       select articleNumber.additionalClassificationCategoryCode).ToList();

        ProductInfo pr = new ProductInfo { Gtin = gtins, BrandName = brandNames, ArticleNr = article };

        return pr;
    }
```

with this method i get three lists from the tabels that i wanted. And after i made the joins i just create a new ProductInfo and add the results to the right lists in the new class.

Comment: How do you connect the 3 lists in your gridView? Do you just connect the rownumbers of each list? What is when the is TradItemBasic with no DescriptionInformation (Then you have 3 lists with different sizes and no other key to connect each other)?